# VB.Net Keyboard Shortcut to auto-generate a Property

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

As the title suggests I am looking for the key sequence to generate the standard Property syntax in a vb.net class. Example below so there is no confusion on what I am asking for. Thanks in advance!

```
Public Property MyProperty() As String
        Get
            Return _MyProperty
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
             Me._MyProperty= value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Type "property" and hit tab twice:

```
Private newPropertyValue As String
Public Property NewProperty() As String
    Get
        Return newPropertyValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        newPropertyValue = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate property in Microsoft visual Studio just write prop and press tab for twice. Property will be generated automatically by Visual Studio.

Thanks,